# MySQL Select ID where all columns under ID don't meet condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table "Payments" where student_id is a foreign key.

```
student_id  Monthpaid       year    payment_id  
51           1              2019    1
52           1              2019    2
51           2              2019    3
```

I tried this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Payments WHERE Monthpaid !=2
```

I get this result:

```
student_id  Monthpaid       year    payment_id  
51           1              2019    1
52           1              2019    2
51           2              2019    3
```

But I want this where ID 52 doesn't have Monthpaid = 2:

```
student_id  Monthpaid       year    payment_id  
51           1              2019    1
```

Comment: can you exlain why this row, number 52 sems tpo be equal

Comment: For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: sorry for caps it is a forgein key

Comment: I really have no idea what is your problem... `SELECT * FROM Payments WHERE Monthpaid !=2` ?

Comment: I don't understand the logic. Can you explain it more clearly please? Explain precisely what the purpose of the query is, and why it should return only the result you mentioned. I also suspect we might need a bigger data sample to fully understand.

Comment: I need to return every Monthpaid where Monthpaid not equal to a number(i.e monthpaid != 2) for every student_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you ware looking for:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and t2.monthpaid = 2
                 );
```

This returns all rows for an `id` where that `id` does not have a month of 2.  That is how I interpret your question.